# Master Detail list in sharePoint and pass parameter in Query string

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have 2 list in my project with SharePoint 2010  (Master and Detail) I created a column named MasterId that make relationship between these two list , I added a custom action for Master list that linked to Detail list NewForm, I want to pass Master list item id to NewForm like this: `http://mySite/List/Detail/NewForm.aspx?MasterId={SelectedItemId}` , but it doesn't work for me.
How can I pass parameter with Query String? 
I used  JavaScript code for solving my problem but it wasn't work too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue with the help of this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194253/How-to-Customize-the-New-Item-form-to-take-paramet)